ASP.NET MVC 5 app loses session variables if run as 'Start without debugging' but runs perfectly with 'Start debugging'
If I run an ASP.NET MVC app from VS under 'Start debugging', it runs perfectly well and returns data from the backend database using the session variables created during login.
If I run it as 'Start without debugging', it throws the toys out and all the session variables are set to nothing (null). I can tell without breakpoints as exceptions are caught and emailed to me.
I will say that sessions have been causing me grief with this - they were not working at all until I set the project SSL Enabled to 'false' then they did work under debugging so I thought I had cured it.
There is one odd thing about this project - all the controllers and views are under areas with none at the root and I suspect this has something to do with it.
Update
Based on the comment by Martin Brown I have set Thread.Sleep at intervals - no difference apart from the time to login.
I created a global integer and during login used that as the UserID which, of course, worked. I then created an ActionResult function for the landing page that is pinged when the landing page loads - this looked up the global integer and added it to the session variable, but as soon as another page is clicked it is, once again, lost.
Update 2
So far, all sessions work in debug
No sessions work if VS is set to debug but 'Start without debugging' is used.
If VS is set to 'Release' and 'Start without debugging' some sessions work - one that doesn't is a DataTable (very small one) saved during ajax calls whilst the user is selecting items to be paid.

First guess is that it is a race condition with the debugging version being slower and leaving the server time to accept and process the login. Try adding a few delays at critical points to see where it is getting stuck (adding asserts to catch it early might also help).

Can you explain more about 'asserts' and how they work?

OK - looked up asserts - another tool I didn't know about. It seems that it loses the session after authentication (it uses Session("UserID") to authenticate).

@Martin Brown - tried what you suggested and updated the question to include that

Have updated the question again - 48 hours later and many configuration changes later and still finding the wall is harder than my head.
